# Swift Array bad access

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I attempted the following simple card example but keep getting error when attempting to access an Array property.  Specifically in func getRandomCard() cards becomes inaccessible after clicking the Flip button.  The behavior is inconsistent, sometimes the error occurs upon the first click on the button and at other times the button can be clicked few time before the error occurs.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks for any insight.

```
//Class PlayingCardDeck
import Foundation

let validSuits = ["♣️", "♦️", "♥️", "♠️"]
let maxRank = 13

class PlayingCardDeck {
    var cards: [PlayingCard] = []

    init() {
        for suit in validSuits {
            for rank in 1...maxRank {
                var card = PlayingCard()
                card.suit = suit
                card.rank = rank
                self.addCard(card)
            }
        }
    }

    func addCard(aCard: PlayingCard) {
        cards.append(aCard)
    }

    func getRandomCard() -> PlayingCard {
        let idx = Int(arc4random()) % cards.count
        let retCard = cards[idx]
        cards.removeAtIndex(idx)
        return retCard
    }
}

//Class PlayingCard
import Foundation

let rankStrings = ["?", "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]

class PlayingCard {    
    var suit = "?"
    var rank = 0

    var contents: String {
        get {
            return rankStrings[rank] + suit
        }
    }
}


//Class ViewController
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var myDeck = PlayingCardDeck()

    @IBOutlet weak var cardLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func flipButton(sender: UIButton) {
        let s = myDeck.getRandomCard().contents
        cardLabel.text = s
    }
}
```

Comment: Verify that the index is valid in the debugger or with a `println()`. Step through and watch the values. Oh BTW, which line and the **exact entire** error message.

Comment: Thanks, indeed it was an index error, but the error message did not say Array index out of range but Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on line let retCard = cards[idx]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would bet that despite the error message, you're actually seeing integer overflow errors. Try using `arc4random_uniform()` instead:

```
 let idx = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(cards.count)))
```

Comment: While `arc4random_uniform()` is a better choice I rather doubt it is an overflow error unless the value of `cards.count` is rather bizarre in which case that is the problem.

Comment: BTW, the proposed code will not compile. Error: 'Int' is not convertible to 'UInt32'. Correct code: `let idx = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(cards.count)))`

Comment: Sorry, missed the initial conversion to `UInt32`.

Comment: @Zaph Wasn't OP getting unexpected negative values in that conversion from `UInt32` to `Int`? What do you call that but overflow? I guess it was both...

Comment: No, I do not think that was the problem. I have a test case that does not have that problem.